# How to stretch an SDL window to fullscreen?

Tags: c, sdl

I am interested in using SDL for graphics. I didn't use it before because when I went into fullscreen mode I would get black borders on the left and right side. I switched to SFML, and it worked just fine because I wasn't in fullscreen mode, but I had a window that stretched to the entire screen. The graphics stretched along with it. I've been noticing a few games are beginning to use a windowed-fullscreen mode.

Is there a way to stretch SDL's window with graphics instead of pure fullscreen mode?

Comment: Assuming that the black bars are there at all because the resolution you chose didn't match the screen (in which case, try to use a resolution that fits perfectly), I *think* this is a per-PC graphics card setting type o'thingy and not something you'd expect to change from your program.

Comment: @Leushenko: Yes, although the goal is to just stretch a borderless window with its graphics to a full screen. I understand that SDL doesn't stretch when going into fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using this function to get fullscreen:

```
SDL_SetWindowFullscreen - https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryVideo
```

And just this function to stretch it to the screen size:

```
SDL_MaximizeWindow - https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MaximizeWindow
```

Hope that was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Apparently, I just get a white, blank square in the center. It doesn't show my bitmap. Without the two lines, it shows the bitmap. This seems to be a limit in the API doing what's best for you. I think I might just stick with SFML. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I tried everything.